# How do I get useState for count to go above 1?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, count

I want the count to increment up by 1 each time an account is created and it saves with that user. I have it so that it will save as user1 but cannot get the count to go above 1 so it just replaces whatever was typed the first time each time a new account is created instead of putting that new information on user2.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import React from 'react';


function CreateAccountPage() {

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();

    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [balance, setBalance] = useState('');
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    

  
    let { from } = location.state || {from: {pathname: '/'}}

   
    function user() {
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    let users = {};
        const incrementCount = () => {
            const newCount = count + 1;
            setCount(newCount);
        };
        

    users["user" + count] = new user("#user" + count);
    
    const createAccount = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
       
        const originalStringifiedForStorgage = JSON.stringify(users);
        localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(users));
       
        console.log(count)
        navigate(from);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Welcome to the CreateAccount Page</h1>
            <form onSubmit={createAccount}>
                <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='E-mail' value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='Username' value={username} onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} />
                <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password' value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
                <button onClick={incrementCount} className='btn btn-primary'>Create Account</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CreateAccountPage;
```

User1 inside the user's key is all saved correctly. I just cannot get it to go to user2 and when I have it console.log(count) it never changes from 1 so each time a new account is typed in it just replaces user1. It should add 1 each time the button is clicked.[Saving Format in LocalStorage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYvia.jpg)

Comment: Try to use an updater: replace setCount(newCount) with setCount((prevCount)=>{return prevCount + 1});       thought I don't believe is this the problem

Comment: No, this did not work. I tried it both with and without the line above it (const newCount = count + 1;) and both times it would not change count above 1

Comment: You have to make users a state. Otherwise, it's just recreating a new variable everytime.

Comment: @nullptr Added const [users, setUsers] = useState({}); to top with rest of states then removed let users = {}; and the count still will not go above 1. Also shows a user0 now and just changes user0 and user1 info each time button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You should move `users` to a state, and use the state setter to update it.

```
function CreateAccountPage() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [balance, setBalance] = useState("");
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState({});

  let { from } = { from: { pathname: "/" } };

  function user() {
    this.email = email;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.balance = balance;
  }

  const incrementCount = () => {
    const newCount = count + 1;
    setCount(newCount);
    setUsers((p) => ({ ...p, ["user" + count]: new user("#user" + count) }));
  };

  const createAccount = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const originalStringifiedForStorgage = JSON.stringify(users);
    localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(users));

    console.log(users);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to the CreateAccount Page</h1>
      <form onSubmit={createAccount}>
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          placeholder="E-mail"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="username"
          placeholder="Username"
          value={username}
          onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button onClick={incrementCount} className="btn btn-primary">
          Create Account
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: this does exactly what I want as long as I stay on the page. If I leave and go to homepage then go back to create account page and try to create another account it will restart its data. Anyway around this?

Comment: you have to store it in localstorage and read it when the page loads